# Java - The method replace() is undefined for the type OutputDocument

Tags: java, eclipse, replace, document, jericho-html-parser

Hey i'm using Eclipse on a Java EE Project and it's showing the problem

> The method replace(Element, String) is undefined for the type
>   OutputDocument

I've already import the **au.id.jericho.lib.html.OutputDocument** library, i don't know what else to do

This is where it's used

```
for (Iterator i = linkStartTags.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
     Element el = (Element)i.next();

     Attributes attributes = el.getAttributes();
     String rel = attributes.getValue(atributo);
     if ((rel != null) && (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(rel)))
     {

       if ((valores != null) && 
         (valores.containsKey(rel))) {
         String valor = (String)valores.get(rel);
         outputDocument.replace(el, valor);
       }
     }
   }
```

P.S I didn't write this code.

***EDIT:***
I was using the wrong version of the library, i was using *jericho-html-2.1* and i changed to *jericho-html-2.3*, now it's working, thanks

Comment: There isn't such method. see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.htmlparser.jericho/jericho-html/2.3/au/id/jericho/lib/html/OutputDocument.java

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I was using the wrong version of the library, i was using *jericho-html-2.1* and i changed to *jericho-html-2.3,* now it's working, thanks